# How can I mock an http call executed in module.run Angular app?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, mocking

I am trying to run the following code (where fusseApp is an angularModule) :

```
fusseApp.run(function(URI, $http){

  $http.get('/check/userLogged').then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
  });
```

PS : Actually my http call is executed in a factory and here we just have a call to this factory

The angularModule is mocked with :

```
angular.module('fusseApp.mainMocks', ['fusseApp', 'fusseApp.loginMocks', 'ngMockE2E', 'ngResource'])
    .run(function($httpBackend, $http) {

...

$httpBackend.whenGET('/check/userLogged').respond(200,response);
```

My problem is that fusseApp.run is executed before the mock module is initialized. So I a have an error :

**Uncaught Error: Unexpected request: GET /check/userLogged**
No more request expected

This problem seems to have been raised in the jasmine unit-test, but I cannot find a solution. Is it possible to run my `$http` call after an event that tells me when the application is completely initialized?

My need is to check that the user is authenticated before displaying any data on screen.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help...

`.run()` is always executed if you set `ng-app=""` in you code, its part of the boostrap process, from there on you can't stop the compile & linking process, but there's many ways to go to prevent a view from being rendered if the user is not logged in:

A) Manual angular boostraping (not so fun but feasible) can be done after authentication is ok, either use jQuery $.ajax or another lib because $http service is out the picture outside NG.

B) But in your `.run()` you have access to `$rootScope` and all of the NG services, therefore you can listen for `$stateChangeStart` and inside the listener perform you auth validation.

This is more or less the best practice for NG authentication, this listener keeps checking every time the user changes state, (which is good so that you can catch sessions expirations), In my code (which I use in prod in various projects) I do exactly this:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (!AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
        $state.transitionTo("login"); // redirect to login page
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

`AuthService` is just a simple service that returns `true` or `false` if the user is authenticated.
In my experience the best solution to hide views to unauthorized users and redirect, is to catch state change process like I show before.
Because you can decorate states these properties are accessible in the `toState` argument (in ui-router at least) So it's possible to do all kinds of fancy stuff like catching user roles and so on...